# LinkButton click event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, click, linkbutton

I bind the click event handler server-side, and pass some additional parameters. This binding is done as part of a repeater data bound event. When I click the LinkButton the event handler's never fired. Can't work out why:

```
lnkUp.Click += (lnkSender, eventArgs) => { lnk_Click(lnkSender, eventArgs, int1, int2, string1); };
```

(I've checked lnkUp is not null etc.).

The event handler:

```
 void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, Int32 int1, Int32 int2, String string1)
 {
      //Do something fantastic
 }
```

In case you're wondering about the mark-up:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUp" runat="server" Text="SomeText"/>
```

Comment: You mean the link button is inside a repeater?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes it is, does that affect the way in which I must bind the event handler?

Comment: Yes it does - it's all about the page life cycle, and I believe ItemDataBound comes after buttons event handlers. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12388171/447356) is probably correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try associate  click event handler in `ItemCreated` event, `not in ItemDataBound`. (Best practise)

And adjust your bind just in `! isPostBack` section , in order to don't erase your registered event.

```
void Repeater_ItemCreated(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
   .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate your answer. Do I still have access to the data item here? I need it.

Comment: I'am happy to help you DeeMac, in lyfecycle phase itemCreated is before ItemDataBound, you access data in ItemDataBound

Comment: string1 comes from a part of the data item, which is used as an argument in the method call - so I'm not sure how I'll use ItemCreated in this case, thanks again.

Comment: Ok i understand your technical choice, DeeMac thank you, you are nice good luck my friend